# Extra td element is displayed while using *ngFor structural directives

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am working on an Angular app that display data on a Button Click. While using table, tr, td for displaying data using *ngFor in . I'm facing some weird issue while displaying on webpage. An Extra td element is generated in DOM.
Following are the screenshot of my HTML Template, data, and how it's been displayed in web browser.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please close the tag.

```
<td>{{ data.id }}<td>
<td>{{ data.name }}<td>
<td>{{ data.age }}<td>
```

should be

```
<td>{{ data.id }}</td>
<td>{{ data.name }}</td>
<td>{{ data.age }}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks Adnan Ahmed for quick response. I was working upon app late night and sometimes it happens that your code is working fine as expected, but due to some typo an some silly mistake it make a nightmare. :)